# How to post function in Codeigniter using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I've some problem in jQuery post. I use Codeigniter, and when I try to post a function with jQuery it's not working.

here's my View file:

```
<div id="dtk"></dtk> <!--I want to get value from this element-->
<?php foreach($result->result as $row){
?>
<input type="hidden" name="id_sesi" id="idse" value="<?php echo $row->id_sesi;?>"> <!--Get value from this element id-->
<?php
}
?>
```

and here's my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(function(){
      setInterval(function(){
          var wkt = $("dtk").html();
          var ses = $("idse").html();
          $.post('controller/update',{ dtk: wkt, id_sesi: ses });
      },1000);
   }
});
```

and here's my controller:

```
function update(){
   $this->load->model('model');
   $data['id_sesi']=$this->input->post('id_sesi');
   $data['dtk']=$this->input->post('dtk');
   $this->model->update($data);
}
```

And I've changed url post to `<?php echo base_url();?>controller/update` still not working.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: And if you use `console.log(wkt+' '+ses);` , what is the output?

Comment: hi, the console result is 500 (Internal Server Error) and POST url is http://localhost/myapp/controller/show/controller/update

I think the url is not working in $.post('controller/update'....

how to post with right url?

Comment: I've changed url post to <?php echo base_url();?>controller/update still not working

Comment: #SOLVED : my model file is wrong, now I can update it when I changed post value. Thanks for your help

Comment: add '/' after the update function

Comment: Side note: `<?php echo base_url('controller/update'); ?>`